# Connecting MYSQL database and python flask app app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

Learning python and building an app for a personal project. For background, using VS Code and have a flask app with the files index.html, server.py, main.js, and style.css.

I'm trying to connect at MYSQL database to my app such that form submissions save down to a database. I have a database created with the tables (and appropriate fields). However, I'm having trouble connecting the database.

Essentially, I'm stuck on filling in the below appropriately and would like if someone could post screeshots or step by step to find the details. I filled it out as understood previously but I run the app through terminal on a MacBook
`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = mysql://username:password@server/db`

My database is firstword_secondword_db.

Some questions:

1. Is username just root user and password I use when clicking into the MySQL connections when opening MySQL? Ideally I want to be able to have a user name of appuser and then is the password.
2. Is it considered "secure enough" to have these values hardcoded into the server.py file of an app?